# TypeScript, parameter after return syntax

Tags: typescript, syntax

I am reading a code like this:

```
const y = ....//some code

const x = ({param1}) => (
 name : 'me',
})(y)
```

My question is, what is that `y` param? Is outside the function params, so, what is it? Is it like a return or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function that's being called immediately with the argument `y`. This is also sometimes called a immediately invoked function expression or [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Here's how it would look split up:

```js
const xFunction = ({param1}) => ({
 name : 'me',
});
const xResult = xFunction(y);
```